# Angular 2 background body only on single page

Tags: css, angular, angular2-routing

i have a Angular 2 project that uses Routes and differents components. one of this components is a login page that don't show any sidebar or footer... So, i need to put ONLY on this page a background (that covers all the body).

I try to use `:host {..}` but don't work.

How can access to the body background property on this component?

This component is on the same level that app.component.
app.component.html has the  and the login component renders here.

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are applying `backgorund`. If you just want to hide side bar and footer for your login page then you can simply hide them based on your active route using `hidden` attribute or `ngIf` directive. Here the refernece for [ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your login.component.html if :host will work and you didn't show it. You can wrap your login.component.html in a div container and add a class to it for its background color. This one works for me.

```
<div class="my-container>
<!--your content --!>
</div>
```

Here's a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/aXxQ5VWjoe2Q4SlVzC0H?p=preview) for the demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend but I'm afraid that this will not work for me. Please see this demo. I need to do something like this http://lbd-pro-angular2.creative-tim.com/login.html

Comment: @AliBriceño I may be misunderstood your question.In the link you provided, what they do is they only have the <router-outlet> in their index.html. The reason for that is to isolate the login page from the sidebar or navbar component.

Comment: Well... I download the project (it haves a free version) and the router-outlet is on a child element called "dashboard". The change of the background they made with jquery but I think that is not a good approach.